# winedt: disable the spell-option globally

Tags: winedt

Using WinEdt I want to disable the spell-option globally (so I do not have to disable it each time opening a document), but I can't find this 'button' in the menue.

Comment: Open the script options interface -> editor ->defaults, change the value `AUTO_SPELL` to 0, then load the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open in the options interface the defaults.ini  script (`-> editor ->defaults`):

[image]

change the value AUTO_SPELL to 0

[image]

then load the script.

[image]